# adding path to centos 7 using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, centos-7

I am migrating from `ubuntu` to `centos` and am in the process of setting up the `centos server'. I am trying to add an executable to path and having difficulty. I`ssh` into the server as root build and install the executable and the add to path using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/package/executable
```

After I do `echo $PATH` I can see that it was added but I can not call the executable.

I have been reading that adding the executable to `/etc/profile.d`is safer but I am not sure and looking for some knowledge. Thank you :).

Maybe:

```
echo 'pathmunge /usr/bin/package/executable' > /etc/profile.d
chmod +x /etc/profile.d
```

results of `ls-ld`

```
cd /usr/bin
ls -ld gatk-4.0.10.1
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  9 15:05 gatk-4.0.10.1
```

Comment: yes it is in a `symbolic directory` within `/usr/bin`, when I do an `ls` the directory the executable is in is blue.  Thank you :).

Comment: I will post back on Monday I seem to be having an issue connecting.... thank you :).

Comment: I apologize for the delay and have made the edit with the `ls -ld`.  The executable resides in the `gatk-4.0.10.1` directory. Thank you :).

Comment: Yes, the executable is within that directory but when I execute the command in the answer my `$PATH` is`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin` Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` should contain directories. If `/usr/bin/package/executable` is literally an executable, i.e. a file that you run, then your `PATH=...` line is wrong. You probably meant:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/usr/bin/package
```